# PHP sha256 password hashing returns different digest when running on linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, sha256, digest

I have the following php class that generates a sha256 digest.

```
<?php

class AuthSha256
{
/**
 * On Bits for sha256 mapping
 *
 * @access  private
 * @var     array
 */
private $m_lOnBits  = array(1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255,511,1023,2047,4095,8191,16383,32767,65535,131071,262143,524287,1048575,2097151,4194303,8388607,16777215,33554431,67108863,134217727,268435455,536870911,1073741823,2147483647);

/**
 * 2nd power sha256 mapping
 *
 * @access  private
 * @var     array
 */
private $m_l2Power  = array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,33554432,67108864,134217728,268435456,536870912,1073741824);

/**
 * Hex mapping sha256 mapping
 *
 * @access  private
 * @var     array
 */
private $K          = array(0x428A2F98,0x71374491,0xB5C0FBCF,0xE9B5DBA5,0x3956C25B,0x59F111F1,0x923F82A4,0xAB1C5ED5,0xD807AA98,0x12835B01,0x243185BE,0x550C7DC3,0x72BE5D74,0x80DEB1FE,0x9BDC06A7,0xC19BF174,0xE49B69C1,0xEFBE4786,0xFC19DC6,0x240CA1CC,0x2DE92C6F,0x4A7484AA,0x5CB0A9DC,0x76F988DA,0x983E5152,0xA831C66D,0xB00327C8,0xBF597FC7,0xC6E00BF3,0xD5A79147,0x6CA6351,0x14292967,0x27B70A85,0x2E1B2138,0x4D2C6DFC,0x53380D13,0x650A7354,0x766A0ABB,0x81C2C92E,0x92722C85,0xA2BFE8A1,0xA81A664B,0xC24B8B70,0xC76C51A3,0xD192E819,0xD6990624,0xF40E3585,0x106AA070,0x19A4C116,0x1E376C08,0x2748774C,0x34B0BCB5,0x391C0CB3,0x4ED8AA4A,0x5B9CCA4F,0x682E6FF3,0x748F82EE,0x78A5636F,0x84C87814,0x8CC70208,0x90BEFFFA,0xA4506CEB,0xBEF9A3F7,0xC67178F2);


/**
 * Perform SHA256 encoding
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string      String to encode
 * @return  string      Encoded string
 */
public function SHA256($sMessage)
{

    $HASH   = array( 
        0x6A09E667, 
        0xBB67AE85, 
        0x3C6EF372, 
        0xA54FF53A, 
        0x510E527F, 
        0x9B05688C, 
        0x1F83D9AB, 
        0x5BE0CD19);

    $M      = $this->ConvertToWordArray( $sMessage );

    for( $i = 0; $i < count($M); $i+=16 )
    {
        $a = $HASH[0];
        $b = $HASH[1];
        $c = $HASH[2];
        $d = $HASH[3];
        $e = $HASH[4];
        $f = $HASH[5];
        $g = $HASH[6];
        $h = $HASH[7];

        for( $j = 0; $j<=47; $j++ )
        {
            if($j < 16) 
            {
                $W[$j] = $M[$j + $i];
            }
            else
            {
                $W[$j] = $this->AddUnsigned($this->AddUnsigned($this->AddUnsigned($this->Gamma1($W[$j - 2]), $W[$j - 7]), $this->Gamma0($W[$j - 15])), $W[$j - 16]);
            }

            $T1 = $this->AddUnsigned($this->AddUnsigned($this->AddUnsigned($this->AddUnsigned($h, $this->Sigma1($e)), $this->Ch($e, $f, $g)), $this->K[$j]), $W[$j]);
            $T2 = $this->AddUnsigned($this->Sigma0($a), $this->Maj($a, $b, $c));

            $h = $g;
            $g = $f;
            $f = $e;
            $e = $this->AddUnsigned($d, $T1);
            $d = $c;
            $c = $b;
            $b = $a;
            $a = $this->AddUnsigned($T1, $T2);
        }

        $HASH[0] = $this->AddUnsigned($a, $HASH[0]);
        $HASH[1] = $this->AddUnsigned($b, $HASH[1]);
        $HASH[2] = $this->AddUnsigned($c, $HASH[2]);
        $HASH[3] = $this->AddUnsigned($d, $HASH[3]);
        $HASH[4] = $this->AddUnsigned($e, $HASH[4]);
        $HASH[5] = $this->AddUnsigned($f, $HASH[5]);
        $HASH[6] = $this->AddUnsigned($g, $HASH[6]);
        $HASH[7] = $this->AddUnsigned($h, $HASH[7]);
    }

    return 
         strtolower(
         substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[0]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[1]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[2]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[3]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[4]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[5]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[6]), -6)
        .substr("00000000".dechex($HASH[7]), -6));
}

/**
 * Left shift a value x bits
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string      String to shift
 * @param   integer     Number of bits to shift
 * @return  string      Shifted string
 */
private function LShift($lValue, $iShiftBits) 
{
    if ($iShiftBits == 0) 
    {
        return $lValue;
    }
    elseif ($iShiftBits == 31) 
    {
        if ($lValue & 1) 
        {
            $un = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
            return reset($un);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    elseif ($iShiftBits < 0 Or $iShiftBits > 31) 
    {
        exit();
    }

    if ($lValue & $this->m_l2Power[31 - $iShiftBits]) 
    {
        $un2=unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
        return (($lValue & $this->m_lOnBits[31 - ($iShiftBits + 1)]) * $this->m_l2Power[$iShiftBits]) | reset($un2);
    }
    else 
    {
        return (($lValue & $this->m_lOnBits[31 - $iShiftBits]) * $this->m_l2Power[$iShiftBits]);
    }
}

/**
 * Right shift a value x bits
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string      String to shift
 * @param   integer     Number of bits to shift
 * @return  string      Shifted string
 */
private function RShift($lValue, $iShiftBits)
{
    if ($iShiftBits == 0) 
    {
        return $lValue;
    }
    elseif ($iShiftBits == 31) 
    {
        $un3 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
        if ($lValue & reset($un3))
        {
            $RShift = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            $RShift = 0;
        }
    }
    elseif ($iShiftBits < 0 Or $iShiftBits > 31) 
    {
        exit();
    }

    $unpack = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x7FFFFFFE')));
    $rese = reset($unpack);
    $RShift = floor(($lValue & $rese) / $this->m_l2Power[$iShiftBits]);

    $unpack1 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
    if ($lValue & reset($unpack1))
    {
        $unpack2 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x40000000')));
        $RShift = ($RShift | floor(reset($unpack2)) / $this->m_l2Power[$iShiftBits - 1]);
    }

    return $RShift;
}

/**
 * Add unsigned
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     Number
 * @param   integer     Number
 * @return  string      Added unsigned integer
 */
private function AddUnsigned($lX, $lY)
{
    $unp1 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
    $unp2 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x80000000')));
    $unp3 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x40000000')));
    $unp4 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x40000000')));
    $lX8 = $lX & reset($unp1);
    $lY8 = $lY & reset($unp2);
    $lX4 = $lX & reset($unp3);
    $lY4 = $lY & reset($unp4);

    $unp5 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0x3FFFFFFF')));
    $lResult = ($lX & reset($unp5)) + ($lY & reset($unp5));

    if ($lX4 & $lY4) 
    {
        $lResult = $lResult ^ reset($unp1) ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8;
    }
    elseif ($lX4 | $lY4) 
    {
        if ($lResult & reset($unp3))
        {
            $unp6 = unpack("l", pack("l", hexdec('0xC0000000')));
            $lResult = $lResult ^ reset($unp6) ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8;
        }
        else 
        {
            $lResult = $lResult ^ reset($unp3) ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $lResult = $lResult ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8;
    }

    return $lResult;
}

/**
 * Ch
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @param   integer     $y
 * @param   integer     $z
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Ch($x, $y, $z)
{
    return (($x & $y) ^ ((~ $x) & $z));
}

/**
 * Maj
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @param   integer     $y
 * @param   integer     $z
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Maj($x, $y, $z)
{
    return (($x & $y) ^ ($x & $z) ^ ($y & $z));
}

/**
 * S
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @param   integer     $n
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function S($x, $n)
{
    return ($this->RShift($x , ($n & $this->m_lOnBits[4])) | $this->LShift($x , (32 - ($n & $this->m_lOnBits[4]))));
}

/**
 * R
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @param   integer     $n
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function R($x, $n)
{
    return $this->RShift($x , ($n & $this->m_lOnBits[4]));
}

/**
 * Sigma0
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Sigma0($x)
{
    return ($this->S($x, 2) ^ $this->S($x, 13) ^ $this->S($x, 22));
}

/**
 * Sigma1
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Sigma1($x)
{
    return ($this->S($x, 6) ^ $this->S($x, 11) ^ $this->S($x, 25));
}

/**
 * Gamma0
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Gamma0($x)
{
    return ($this->S($x, 7) ^ $this->S($x, 18) ^ $this->R($x, 3));
}

/**
 * Gamma1
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   integer     $x
 * @return  mixed       No idea...
 */
private function Gamma1($x)
{
    return ($this->S($x, 17) ^ $this->S($x, 19) ^ $this->R($x, 10));
}

/**
 * Convert to a word array
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string      Word to convert
 * @return  array       Word array
 */
private function ConvertToWordArray($sMessage)
{
    $BITS_TO_A_BYTE = 8;
    $BYTES_TO_A_WORD = 4;
    $BITS_TO_A_WORD = 32;
    $MODULUS_BITS = 512;
    $CONGRUENT_BITS = 448;

    $lMessageLength = strlen($sMessage);

    $lNumberOfWords = (floor(($lMessageLength + floor(($MODULUS_BITS - $CONGRUENT_BITS) / $BITS_TO_A_BYTE)) / floor($MODULUS_BITS / $BITS_TO_A_BYTE)) + 1) * floor($MODULUS_BITS / $BITS_TO_A_WORD);
    for($i = 0; $i < $lNumberOfWords; $i++)
    {
        $lWordArray[$i]="";
    }

    $lBytePosition = 0;
    $lByteCount = 0;
    do
    {
        $lWordCount = floor($lByteCount / $BYTES_TO_A_WORD);

        $lBytePosition = (3 - ($lByteCount % $BYTES_TO_A_WORD)) * $BITS_TO_A_BYTE;

        $lByte = ord(substr($sMessage, $lByteCount, 1));

        $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = $lWordArray[$lWordCount] | $this->LShift($lByte , $lBytePosition);
        $lByteCount++;
    }
    while ($lByteCount < $lMessageLength);

    $lWordCount = floor($lByteCount / $BYTES_TO_A_WORD);
    $lBytePosition = (3 - ($lByteCount % $BYTES_TO_A_WORD)) * $BITS_TO_A_BYTE;

    $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = $lWordArray[$lWordCount] | $this->LShift(0x80 , $lBytePosition);

    $lWordArray[$lNumberOfWords - 1] = $this->LShift($lMessageLength , 3);
    $lWordArray[$lNumberOfWords - 2] = $this->RShift($lMessageLength , 29);

    return $lWordArray;
}
}
```

here is sample code for generating a digest

```
<?php 
require_once('AuthSha256.php');

 $pwd = '1!aAqwerty';
 $c = new AuthSha256();
 print_r($c-> SHA256($pwd));
?>
```

When i execute  this class on Linux I get this digest `97bc61212297bf380d5462d827b182adf6f956c855ec9c1c` but when I execute the exactly same code on windows I get for the same password '1!aAqwerty' a completely different digest. `20fc88c269c75bda2902f99d020fa966c4e550b42bedddd9`.
Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: Why would you want to make such a thing while you can just use `hash('sha256', 'input')` ?

Comment: big-endian/little-endian differences? 32-bit/64-bit differences?

Comment: Actually, the correct `sha256` hash for `1!aAqwerty` would be `10a4b98bcc1c8b31202c4f50d7a7897ee685be85b64fc39d346da480e63b347e`, so both of your calculated hashes are wrong -> your class does something wrong. But why not just use `hash('sha256', 'input')`, as Daan said?

Comment: @FoxRider the first function (SHA256)  of the class has a for loop that iterates from zero to <=47 thats why the digest that you are getting with the default sha256 method is different. i have calculated the digest with this class inorder to be able to login old users to the new system. i am trying to understand why the same code on different operating systems doesnt produce the same digest.

Comment: @MarkBaker both windows and linux systems are 64-bit. But if what you say about big-endian little-endian differences is true how can i debug this inorder to understand what is happening?

Comment: Are both versions of PHP 64-bit; just because the OS is 64-bit doesn't mean that the version of PHP that you're running is 64-bit.... check the value of the `PHP_INT_SIZE` constant, a value of 8 means 64-bit, 4 means 32-bit

Comment: Use `function isLittleEndian() {
    $testint = 0x00FF;
    $p = pack('S', $testint);
    return $testint===current(unpack('v', $p));
}` to check for little/big-endian

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP_INT_SIZE on linux is 8 but in windows is 4. Can i do something about it? i googled but no luck!

Comment: It is possible to get 64-bit PHP for Windows Visit http://windows.php.net/download/ and look for the `x64` versions

Comment: @MarkBaker very usefull comment about the php_int_size! i  masked off the low 32 bits of the int variables that i use like this `$val = $something & 0xFFFFFFFF;` and my problem is now solved!